# Zip attachement with subsequent message

Tags: c#, email-attachments

I have bunch of XML files which some do have attachments and some don't
the ones that do have attachments will have tag something.pdf

below is the code to get the value of the file name which works if I run on against one xml file:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.Load(@"C:\Temp\XML\test.xml");

        XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/FileDump/Message/Attachment");
        foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
        {
            string FileName = xn["FileName"].InnerText;
            string FileID = xn["FileID"].InnerText;
            Console.WriteLine("Name: {0} {1}  ", FileName, FileID);              
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
```

my question is as follow:
how do I run the code on all the xml files in the c:\Temp\XML directory and read the tag FileName then look for the file in the  c:\att.
the search pattern should be the tag value of the FileName.
once those attachment are identified zip the message and the attachments in one file.

Thank you all in advance

Comment: You should refactor the code you have above into a loop.  Loop through the results of a call to `System.IO.Directory.GetFiles` specifying a search pattern for XML files (*.xml).  It will return an array of file names which you can pass to the XmlDocument to load them.  Each time you identify an attachment you can use a library like DotNetZip to zip it with the XML file and output the result to a file.

Comment: How do I pass the tag values of the FileName to search for a file with that name in att directory?

Comment: Here is my updated code which is not giving me the result expected:   1- extract the tag value

Comment: I solved my issue and if everyone is interested I can pot the code